# Sonar: local or external MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

We are trying to set up a dedicated/single Sonar instance at an organization level with close to 60 projects (different languages) with MySQL DB. The goal is to make sure that the system performs optimally, i.e both Sonar and MySQL DB.

Below are the hardware specification for the VM that we are planning to procure.

RAM: 8GB , Hard Disk: 100GB, OS: Windows 2008 server

The only question with this set up that we want to have is, whether to have Sonar and MySQL running in the same machine or have a dedicated machine to run MySQL server in the same network.

Any inputs is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Sonar install consists of 2 parts: the Sonar server, and the Sonar batch (usually run through a CI software like Jenkins).

Our advise is to have both parts as close to the DB as possible. This is all the more important for **the batch part** which heavily queries and updates the DB when doing analyses. Having the DB far from the CI server that runs Sonar analyses can have a huge impact on performances.

Comment: Thank you Fabrice for your inputs. To run Sonar analysis using a CI server closer to the Sonar server may be bit tricky since the projects are located in different locations(but in the same network) and they may have their own CI set up which will talk to this Sonar instance. But, just to be clear, you suggest to have both the DB and Sonar web app to be on the same machine?

Comment: Well, the real bottleneck (in terms of performances) is not between the Sonar server and the DB, but between the CI server(s) and the DB. May your CI server(s) be on the same network as the DB, performances will drop and analysis time will greatly increase if they are hundreds of kilometers far from each other. We have an open ticket about this topic (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2119), but the solution is not trivial to implement.